Automate deployment activity via API or SSJS to Pause, Save and Resume API Event journey after a change to the Email tempate
We would like to have external management of transaction specific content blocks within email templates used in API Event journeys.
We plan to have the Email template with standard header (top panel) and footer (bottom panel) with the centre panel (html) that would include the transaction specific content built and owned by the development team and deployed using the Asset management APIs (<POST / PATCH> /asset/v1/content/assets).
That center panel would be a content block used by reference - either ContentBlockbyID("nn") or ContentBlockbyName("abc").
With ongoing maintenance/enhancement that would require the centre panel to be changed, we would like to automate the deployment including the need to pause, publish (or save) and re-activate the journey.
I could not find any resources (in this forum or in Salesforce Help docs) on how that could be achieved. There appears to be no REST APIs or SSJS scripts that could be triggered from Automation Studio.
Reaching out to the network to understand if that is feasible and a reference or example of how it could be achieved.

All of it is feasible.
I don't fully understand what you mean by "There appears to be no REST APIs or SSJS scripts that could be triggered from Automation Studio."
,but you can absolutely run SSJS script via the SSJS Script activity in Automation Studio, and you can send absolutely send API calls from SSJS script.
There is ample material on these topics in the public docs.
Content Builder REST API - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/content-api.html - can be used to update an asset using PATCH.
given you can construct a payload and get a token, here are functions to do so;
function updateAssetCall(assetId, payload, accessToken) {
    var endpoint = restEndpoint + "asset/v1/content/assets/" + assetId;
    var method = "PATCH";
    var contentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    var headerName = "Authorization";
    var headerValue = "Bearer " + accessToken;
    return sendApiCall(endpoint, method, contentType, payload, headerName, headerValue);
}

function sendApiCall(endpoint,method,contentType,payload,headerName,headerValue) {
    var marker = "1"
    var endpoint = endpoint
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(endpoint);
    req.method = method;
    req.setHeader(headerName,headerValue);
    req.contentType = contentType;
    if (method == "POST" || method == "PATCH" ) {
        if (typeof payload == 'object') {
            req.postData = Stringify(payload);
        } else {
            req.postData = payload;
        }
    }
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;

    try {
        var resp = req.send();  
        respJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
        
    } catch (e) {
        respJSON = e
        return e
    }
return respJSON;
}

Journey emails in regular journeys are triggered send definitions - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/triggeredsenddefinition.html.
WSProxy can be used to pause / publish / restart a triggered send definition. No need for API infrastructure here, this can be done with plain SSJS and WSProxy, given you can construct an array of objects with customerKey, businessUnit and triggeredSendName for each mail you want to update;
Platform.Load("core",1);
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

function republishTS(data) {
    var dataArray = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(data);
    var triggeredSendLogDE = "triggeredSendUpdateLogs";
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        var prefixedGUID = "ts_" + GUID();
        var dataObject = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(dataArray[i]);

        var customerKey = dataObject.customerKey;
        var businessUnit = dataObject.businessUnit;
        var triggeredSendName = dataObject.triggeredSendName;
        
        prox.resetClientIds();
        prox.setClientId({ "ID": businessUnit })

        var resultPause = prox.updateItem(
            "TriggeredSendDefinition", 
            {
                "CustomerKey": customerKey, 
                "TriggeredSendStatus": "Inactive"
            }
        );
        var resultPublish = prox.updateItem(
            "TriggeredSendDefinition", 
            {
                "CustomerKey": customerKey, 
                "RefreshContent": true
            }
        );
        var resultRestart = prox.updateItem(
            "TriggeredSendDefinition", 
            {
                "CustomerKey": customerKey, 
                "TriggeredSendStatus": "Active"
            }
        );    
    }
    return res;
}

